# How to properly insert data in 2D array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

Here i have 3 2D arrays, `arrayActive`, `arrayDeath`, `arrayRecovery` . I'm trying to insert data to  each of my arrays using for loop. Then I'm trying to substract other 2 arrays with `arrayActive`. But the output I'm getting is incorrect.

These are the 3 arrays:

```
int arrayActive[4][1];

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<1; y++)
        {
            printf("Enter the number of active cases in the state %d are : ",i+1);
            scanf("%d",  &arrayActive[i][y]);
        }
    }


    int arrayDeath[4][1];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        for(int y=0; y<1; y++)
        {
            printf("Enter the number of Death cases in the state %d are : ",y+1);
            scanf("%d",  &arrayDeath[i][y]);
        }
    }


    int arrayRecover[4][1];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<1; y++)
        {
            printf("Enter the number of recovery cases in the state %d are : ",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&arrayRecover[i][y]);

        }
    }
```

And here I'm trying to get all the output after subtraction which is not correct:

```
 int activeCasesStateWise[4];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
for(int y=0; y<1; y++)
{

    activeCasesStateWise[i]= arrayActive[i][y]-arrayRecover[i][y] - arrayDeath[i][y];

    printf("Here array active case %d and recover case %d and death cases %d the So  cumulative active cases for state 1 are %d \n", arrayActive[i][y],arrayRecover[i][y],arrayDeath[i][y],activeCasesStateWise[i]);
}
```

Comment: `int arrayActive[4][1];

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)` When you define an array with size 4, the valid indices are 0-3. The loop you have here will execute from i = 0 to 4 invoking undefined behavior in the last iteration. You should either increase the size from 4 to 5 or change 5 to 4 in the loop condition.

Comment: Why do you have a 2D array where the 2nd dimension has size 1? Is this some API reason?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an array of 4 rows and in the for loop, you are adding values for the 5th row as well. Hence, your program is not working and getting crashed.
You will have to change the condition for all outer loops as below:
for(int i=0; **i<4**; i++)